# SQL show UserCode from the highest value in column

Tags: sql, sql-server, filter, count, sql-order-by

I am making a select from a table that has alums, but those alums can have a "level" being 01, 02, 03, 04, 05 or 99 and if I select a distinct(code) there will be 2 or 3 files of the same "code" with different "level". I want to be able to ONLY get the "code" with the higher "level" anytime.

Example of my code:

```
select  
Level,
count(Code) as Atendee,
count(CASE WHEN CodPlace = 01 THEN (Atendee) ELSE null END ) as AtendeeCho,
count(CASE WHEN CodPlace = 02 THEN (Atendee) ELSE null END ) as AtendeeSB,
count(CASE WHEN CodPlace = 14 THEN (Atendee) ELSE null END ) as AtendeeIca 
from  #TempoPar  
group by Level 
order by Level
```

And here is the result:

```
Level Atendee AtendeeCho AtendeeSB AtendeeIca

1      3       2           0        1

2      0       0           0        0

3      2       2           0        0

99     1       1           0        0
```

Problem is that the one who is in AtendeeCho from level 1, 2 and 99 is the same person and he should only be on 99 or 3 if he wasn't on 99.

Thanks in advance!

Data example:

```
Code ( user)  Level Career CodPlace 
12345         1     9      01
12345         3     15     01
12346         1     10     14
12347         1     10     01
12345         3     15     01
12347         99    15     01
```

Now, this is what I require:

From the data sample:

```
Code ( user)  Level Career CodPlace 
12345         3     15     01
12346         1     10     14
12347         99    15     01
```

In the final output with the corrected data it should be:
Level Atendee AtendeeCho AtendeeSB AtendeeIca

```
1      1       0           0        1

2      0       0           0        0

3      1       1           0        0

99     1       1           0        0
```

Comment: Can you post sample input data & sample output please.

Comment: Hi! Yes, I just added an example at the end of the original question, the output is on the "result" part. Thanks in advance! :D

Comment: You show the result you are getting. What is the result you want? Show that as a table.

Comment: From sample data, I don't see that AttendeeCho level 1, 2, 99 is same person. Level 2 and 99 show same user.

Comment: What is `Inscritos`?

Comment: I tried your query and the result is not exactly what you show. Attendee and AttendeeIca data is reversed order.

Comment: I just updated the current output and added a new output, also edited the data example and added the data that should be used from that example. "Inscritos" Should be "atendee" I just corrected that, thanks for pointing that out!